# Xml Deserializer to deserialize 2-Dimensional Array

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, multidimensional-array, deserialization

I have a problem about deserialize an array ( int[*,*])
I have an array `int[*,*]` and i need to serialize and deserialize it. How to do it with XMLSerializer??

```
    int[,] B = new int[2,5];        
    public int[,] XMLIntArray
    {
        set { B = value; }
        get { return B; }
    }
```

Comment: Well, what did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: I dont know how I can do this. Any ideas((

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not use XmlSerializer for multidimensional arrays. But you can use jagged arrays. `int[][] B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately multidimensional arrays serialization are not supported by  XmlSerializer  or  DataContractSerializer the only way (not human readable) is  to use binary serialization like in this  example

```
   public static void Main()
    {

        int[,] B = new int[2, 5];
        B[0, 0] = 5;
        B[0, 1] = 3;
        B[0, 2] = 5;  

        DeepSerialize<int[,]>( B,"test3");
        int[,] des= DeepDeserialize<int[,]>("test3");



    }

 public static void DeepSerialize<T>(T obj,string fileName)
    {
        //            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        FileStream str = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        binaryFormatter.Serialize(str, obj);
        str.Close();
    }
    public static T DeepDeserialize<T>(string fileName)
    {
        //            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        FileStream str = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);

        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        T returnValue = (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(str);            
        str.Close();
        return returnValue; 
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't say **the only way** It is the only way *you know*.  See this code:  `int[,] B = new int[2, 5] { {1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9,10} };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(B);
    var B2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<int[,]>(json);`

Comment: Sorry, but I need to serialize to XML

Answer (score 0):

You cannot serialze a int[,] but you can serialize a int[][]. Before serializing your array, just convert it like that:

```
var my2dArray = new int[2,5];
var myJaggedArray = new int [2][];

for(int i = 0 ; i < my2DArray.GetLength(0) ; i ++)
{
    myJaggedArray[i] = new int[my2DArray.GetLength(1)];

    for(int j = 0 ; j < my2DArray.GetLength(1) ; j ++)
        myJaggedArray[i][j] = my2DArray[i,j]; 
}
```